# Can the sum of two sides of a triangle be less than the third side

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I was studying elementary vectors and complex numbers together, when I thought: is it possible for the sum of two sides of a triangle be less than the third side.

Can a triangle with complex sides (or any type of numbers invented by man) ever be such that: sum of its two sides is less than the third?

Comment: Google triangle inequality.

Comment: Triangle inequality says the opposite.

Comment: How do you define a triangle with complex sides?

Comment: Triangle who sides are complex numbers. That is the vertices lie in argand plane

Comment: How do you compare complex numbers?

Comment: Sry didn't think about that

Comment: A triangle on the Argand plane is just a triangle on the plane. The lengths of the sides are real numbers (equal to the magnitudes of the differences of the complex numbers that are the *vertices* of the triangle).

Comment: When I say the vertices lie in argand plane, I mean the sides are complex numbers not their moduli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triangle inequality
$$
||x+y||\le ||x||+||y||
$$
is one of the defining properties of a norm in a vector space, so in  any normed vector space this inequality is verified.

But, if we relax this request, we can have a vector space that is equipped with a symmetric bilineaar form that is not positive defined, and, from this form, we can define a ''distance'' that does not necessarlily satisfies the triangle inequality.

We can construct a vector space of this kind using immaginary coordinates as in the case of the relativity theory, that can be formulated in a space with three real coordinates (the ''space'' coordinates) and one imaginary coordinates ( the ''time'' coordinate). This space is called  a [Minkowski space-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) and  in it we can define a ''Minkowski distance''  that is [not positive defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space). This means that the square of the distance between two points (events) of this space can be negative.

In this space there are points such that the [trangle inequality is reversed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reversal_in_Minkowski_space), in the sense that we have:
$$
||x+y||\ge ||x||+||y||
$$